# Make an HTML element 'float'

Tags: html, css

I want an HTML element (let say a span or div) to be present on the page, but not take up any space, so I can switch on and off the visibility property, and nothing moves but the span disappears.
for example take a table. I want an 'edit' label to show at each row, when I move the mouse over. But I don't want it to take up space from the table width. I just want it to 'float' beside the table.
Any ideas how to achieve this?

- I can **not** to use javascript. So I'll be very glad if this is possible with CSS only.
- I have tried to use float, its not good because no element overlaps with it. (And i do want overlapping.)

Comment: do you have an example of this?

Comment: Absolute positioning, is not really possible because I am generating the table dynamically. and I don't want it to break when the window is resized. And why did you rate me down?? you really think I have not tried this 2 days before asking???
Daniel, I got more or less what I needed from the answer I selected. But thanks anyway

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you're after a CSS Tooltip. Here's an example of one:
http://psacake.com/web/jl.asp

Answer (score 3):

```
div {
    position: absolute;
    left: 100px;
    top: 100px;
}
```

This will take the div and position it relative to the first containing element with position other than `static`. If you have an item with a position of static (the default) or relative, it will affect the document flow and hence the position of other elements. If you set the position to absolute, it takes it out of the document flow and lets you 'drop' it onto the page at whatever pixel position you like. :D

**[Css position property](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_position.asp)**

Answer (score 2):

Without using javascript i suppose you could use CSS `:hover`. Like this:

```
<style type="text/css">
#world { display: none; }
#hello:hover #world { display: block; }
</style>
<div id="hello">
    hello
    <div id="world">world</div>
</div>
```

Demo: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gEBcF/2/)

Answer (score 2):

The "float" property does not "float" an object over the other elements. It "float"s the element to one side or another.

To put an object over another object, use the z-index property combined with the position property.

```
z-index: 500;
position: absolute;
left: 50px;
top: 50px;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this effect by making an additional column on the edge of your table that is invisible until its row is hovered over. You want to use `visibility`, *not* `display`, to hide and show because `visibility` maintains the allocated space of the cell.

Demo: **http://jsfiddle.net/sCrS6/**

You should be able to easily duplicate the code to make it work for your particular page.

This method also has the advantage of working more consistently across web browsers than using `positioning`, which often starts to have weird in IE behavior after a couple of elements are nested.